# How can I create a good and simple bottom border that is easy to remember

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a bottom border to work but it is not working as I want. When I create my border there is a small line below the border that is still the background. How can i fix this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bottomborder"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bottomborder {
    background-color: black;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you take a screenshot with what you are talking about?

Comment: Your question is not adequate, but  for creating black bottom border.
eg. [border-bottom : 1px solid black];

Comment: Try to make sure there is not other elements that may be adding unwanted margins or padding to your layout. it's tough to tell without the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

What Exactly you want?

Your information and code is not sufficient still Please see this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/3d6c5a18/)

```css
   .bottomborder
{
    background-color: black;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    border-bottom:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottomborder"></div>
```

Note: Your are not closing `<div>` properly

Comment: You have an edit on the question where you correct the div1 mistake. Usually, this is a bad idea. Maybe the original problem with the OP is what you are correcting. If this is the case, the question looses all the meaning .

Answer (score 0):

You could do it easily by `inspecting element`. Also the way [Rawat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2008045/rawat-raman) suggested.

Have a look here:-

```
<div class="bottomborder" id="div1"></div>
```

CSS:-

```
.bottomborder {
        background-color: black;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        height: 20px;
        margin-left: -30px;
        margin-right: -30px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid green;
    }
```

See the [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nadeem/pffkczmy/6/) here

Hope it helps

Comment: well. its not exactly how i want. i mean, i have a border beneath my border that has the same color as my background. and i am trying to get that away.

Answer (score 0):

Just use border instead of background-color like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="bottomborder"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bottomborder {
    background-color: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: -20px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #000;
}
```

P.s. you specified two height properties of `20px` as well as `auto` on the div.